# Labeling a GitHub repository

Tags: github

[image: opic)]

See the picture, this example repository 'octobox' is labeled `ruby` `notificagtions` `inbox` etc. How can I label my own repository like that?

Comment: I've got a `Manage topics` link beneath the description on my repositories, I guess you do not have this link?

Comment: @tkausl thanks, can't believe I missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be "**topics**": see "[Classifying your repository with topics](https://help.github.com/en/articles/classifying-your-repository-with-topics)"

> Under your repository description, click Add topics.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/add-topics-link.png]